# how to submit a form after MySql response

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have html code that creates a form and inside that form I have a username textbox with a submit button. The problem is that when I press that submit button it automatically goes to a new link but I want it to wait for response from server so I could check whether that the user has been taken or not.

Here is my html code

```
<form class="Registration_Form" id="Registration_Form"
action="../postr" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="Inputbox"name="UserName"
    class="Inputbox"name="UserName" onclick="textboxfocus(this)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="SumbitForm_btn" 
    class="SumbitForm_btn" name="Submit_btn"/>
</form>
```

Comment: So AJAX.......?

Comment: Use event.preventDefault()

Comment: i mean like to send my username to server first then so the server could check if the username is available an then the form could be submited something like we hav in google or facebook

Comment: Just google "ajax form submit" and submit the form via ajax to a page that hits the db checking the username and returns a response to your javascript that either shows an error to the user that the name has been taken or submits the form if the name has not been taken.

Comment: i am not really good at googling could you please provide me a link,

Comment: Right after SO, Google is a programmer's best friend. It's best to take a stab at it and post your code if you run into trouble. Google the words "ajax form submit" and, for more recent code examples, you can use Google's search tools to limit the results to the last year.